# Preferred internet connection to transport of 4 TB CSV files to Amazon (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to transfer bunch of CSV files with around 4 TB in total to AWS.
What is preferred internet connection from my ISP which can handle this transfer or 
 link does not play any role. My link is 70 Mbps Upload/Download Dedicated. Is this enough or I need to increase my link speed?

Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 TB = 4,194,304 mbyte

70 mbit/sec ~= 8.75 mbyte/sec (approximate because there will be network overheads)

Dividing results in 479,349 seconds, or 5.55 days

Increasing your link speed will certainly improve this, but you'll probably find that you get more improvement using compression (CSV implies text with a numeric bias, which compresses extremely well).

You don't say what you'll be uploading to, nor how you'll be using the results. If you're uploading to S3, I'd suggest using GZip (or another compression format) to compress the files before uploading, and then let the consumers decompress as needed. If you're uploading to EFS, I'd create an EC2 instance to receive the files and use `rsync` with the `-z` option (which will compress over the wire but leave the files uncompressed on the destination). Of course, you may still prefer pre-compressing the files, to save on long-term storage costs.